# Client waits for a message from server on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, client

I'm just trying to do a connection from a server on Java and a client on android. my problem is that I made a thread for waiting a message to print it on a EditText. I only recive the first message that is sent from the server like a default message, saying "connection succesful" Now, when I send a second message the app just close and I have to force the close. I'm sure that the problem is on the thread that is where I have the method leermensajes(). I don't know what to do, now that I'm newbie on Android and also I don't have much experience programming.

Here is the client code

```
 public class ClienteActivity extends Activity {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            private ObjectOutputStream salida;
            private ObjectInputStream entrada;
            private String mensaje = "";
            private String servidorChat;
            private int puerto;
            private Socket cliente;
            private CheckBox check;
            private Button boton;
            private EditText mensajeservidor;
            private AutoCompleteTextView text;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                // Componentes graficos
                //Intento dar una accion a un boton
                boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
                mensajeservidor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                servidorChat = "151.57.15.160"; // servidor  
                puerto = 12345; // puerto

                try {
                    cliente = new Socket( servidorChat , puerto );
                    salida = new ObjectOutputStream( cliente.getOutputStream() );
                    salida.flush();
                    entrada = new ObjectInputStream( cliente.getInputStream() );
                    //entrada = new ObjectInputStream( cliente.getInputStream() );
                    leermensajes();
                    //mensaje = ( String ) entrada.readObject();
                    //CharSequence cs = mensaje;
                    //mensajeservidor.setText(cs); 

                    }

                catch ( EOFException excepcionEOF ) {
                    Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this,"El cliente termino la conexion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        //Alert que avisa del error
                        Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.UnkowHost,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.ConectionError,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                } 


        }

        protected void onDestroy() {
                try {
                        salida.close();
                        cliente.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.errorDesconexion,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                }
                super.onDestroy();

        }

        public void onEnviarClick(View button1) {
                try {
                        if (cliente != null) {
                                salida.writeObject("CLIENTE>>>"+text.getText().toString());
                                salida.flush(); // vacíar búfer de salida para enviar
                                                                // información de encabezado
                        } else
                                Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.ConectionError,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.UnkowHost,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.ConectionError,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                }

        }

        public void onConectarDesconectar(View checkBox) {
                if (!check.isChecked()) {
                        boton.setEnabled(false);
                        text.setEnabled(false);


                } else {
                        boton.setEnabled(true);
                        text.setEnabled(true);

                }

        }

        public void leermensajes(){
             new Thread(new Runnable(){

                 public synchronized void stop(){
                     cliente = null;
                     salida = null;
                     entrada = null;

             }
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        entrada = new ObjectInputStream( cliente.getInputStream() );
                        mensaje = ( String ) entrada.readObject();
                        while (true){

                        CharSequence cs = mensaje;
                        mensajeservidor.setText(cs);
                        }

                        }

                    catch ( EOFException excepcionEOF ) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this,"El cliente termino la conexion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                          //  //Alert que avisa del error
                            Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.UnkowHost,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ClienteActivity.this, R.string.ConectionError,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            android.util.Log.w("¡¡¡ERROR!!!", e.getMessage());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    stop();
                }

            }).start();
        }
   }
```

this is the Server code but it works perfectly

```
public Servidor()
   {
      super( "Servidor" );

      Container contenedor = getContentPane();

      // crear campoIntroducir y registrar componente de escucha
      campoIntroducir = new JTextField();
      campoIntroducir.setEditable( false );
      campoIntroducir.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {

            // enviar mensaje al cliente
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evento )
            {
               enviarDatos( evento.getActionCommand() );
               campoIntroducir.setText( "" );
            }
         }
      ); 

      contenedor.add( campoIntroducir, BorderLayout.NORTH );

      // crear areaPantalla
      areaPantalla = new JTextArea();
      contenedor.add( new JScrollPane( areaPantalla ),
      BorderLayout.CENTER );

      setSize( 300, 150 );
      setVisible( true );

   } // fin del constructor de Servidor

   // configurar y ejecutar el servidor
   public void ejecutarServidor()
   {
      // configurar servidor para que reciba conexiones; procesar las conexiones
      try {

         // Paso 1: crear un objeto ServerSocket.
         servidor = new ServerSocket( 12345, 100 );

         while ( true ) {

            try {
               esperarConexion(); // Paso 2: esperar una conexión.
               obtenerFlujos();        // Paso 3: obtener flujos de entrada y salida.
               procesarConexion(); // Paso 4: procesar la conexión.
            }

            // procesar excepción EOFException cuando el cliente cierre la conexión
            catch ( EOFException excepcionEOF ) {
               System.err.println( "El servidor terminó la conexión" );
            }

            finally {
               cerrarConexion();   // Paso 5: cerrar la conexión.
               ++contador;
            }

         } // fin de instrucción while

      } // fin del bloque try

      // procesar problemas con E/S
      catch ( IOException excepcionES ) {
         excepcionES.printStackTrace();
      }

   } // fin del método ejecutarServidor

   // esperar que la conexión llegue, después mostrar información de la conexión
   private void esperarConexion() throws IOException
   {
      mostrarMensaje( "Esperando una conexión\n" );
      conexion = servidor.accept(); // permitir al servidor aceptar la conexión
      mostrarMensaje( "Conexión " + contador + " recibida de: " +
         conexion.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
   }

   // obtener flujos para enviar y recibir datos
   private void obtenerFlujos() throws IOException
   {
      // establecer flujo de salida para los objetos
      salida = new ObjectOutputStream( conexion.getOutputStream() );
      salida.flush(); // vaciar búfer de salida para enviar información de encabezado

      // establecer flujo de entrada para los objetos
      entrada = new ObjectInputStream( conexion.getInputStream() );

      mostrarMensaje( "\nSe recibieron los flujos de E/S\n" );
   }

   // procesar la conexión con el cliente
   private void procesarConexion() throws IOException
   {
      // enviar mensaje de conexión exitosa al cliente
      String mensaje = "Conexión exitosa";
      enviarDatos( mensaje );

      // habilitar campoIntroducir para que el usuario del servidor pueda enviar mensajes
      establecerCampoTextoEditable( true );

      do { // procesar los mensajes enviados por el cliente

         // leer el mensaje y mostrarlo en pantalla
         try {
            mensaje = ( String ) entrada.readObject();
            mostrarMensaje( "\n" + mensaje );
         }

         // atrapar problemas que pueden ocurrir al tratar de leer del cliente
         catch ( ClassNotFoundException excepcionClaseNoEncontrada ) {
            mostrarMensaje( "\nSe recibió un tipo de objeto desconocido" );
         }

      } while ( !mensaje.equals( "CLIENTE>>> TERMINAR" ) );

   } // fin del método procesarConexion

   // cerrar flujos y socket
   private void cerrarConexion()
   {
      mostrarMensaje( "\nFinalizando la conexión\n" );
      establecerCampoTextoEditable( false ); // deshabilitar campoIntroducir

      try {
         salida.close();
         entrada.close();
         conexion.close();
      }
      catch( IOException excepcionES ) {
         excepcionES.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   // enviar mensaje al cliente
   private void enviarDatos( String mensaje )
   {
      // enviar objeto al cliente
      try {
         salida.writeObject( "SERVIDOR>>> " + mensaje );
         salida.flush();
         mostrarMensaje( "\nSERVIDOR>>> " + mensaje );
      }

      // procesar problemas que pueden ocurrir al enviar el objeto
      catch ( IOException excepcionES ) {
         areaPantalla.append( "\nError al escribir objeto" );
      }
   }

   // método utilitario que es llamado desde otros subprocesos para manipular a
   // areaPantalla en el subproceso despachador de eventos
   private void mostrarMensaje( final String mensajeAMostrar )
   {
      // mostrar mensaje del subproceso de ejecución despachador de eventos
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable() {  // clase interna para asegurar que la GUI se actualice apropiadamente

            public void run() // actualiza areaPantalla
            {
               areaPantalla.append( mensajeAMostrar );
               areaPantalla.setCaretPosition(
                  areaPantalla.getText().length() );
            }

         }  // fin de la clase interna

      ); // fin de la llamada a SwingUtilities.invokeLater
   }

   // método utilitario que es llamado desde otros subprocesos para manipular a
   // campoIntroducir en el subproceso despachador de eventos
   private void establecerCampoTextoEditable( final boolean editable )
   {
      // mostrar mensaje del subproceso de ejecución despachador de eventos
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
         new Runnable() {  // clase interna para asegurar que la GUI se actualice apropiadamente

            public void run()  // establece la capacidad de modificar a campoIntroducir
            {
               campoIntroducir.setEditable( editable );
            }

         }  // fin de la clase interna

      ); // fin de la llamada a SwingUtilities.invokeLater
   }

   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
      Servidor aplicacion = new Servidor();
      aplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      aplicacion.ejecutarServidor();
   }

}  // fin de la clase Servidor
```

Comment: Shouldn't the readObject() call be inside the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You open new streams for each message. That's not the way it should work when doing networking. You should let the stream open, send and receive stuff, then, when done, close it.

Comment: can you explain to me what should I do? sorry but I don't really get what you'r exactly trying to say to me.

Comment: en la method leerMensajes, no deberia abrir nigun nuevo stream pero utilizar el mismo stream que initializaste connectando al servidor. Si abras un nuevo stream cada vez, vas a cerrar tambien el stream previo (con el garbage collector) y cerrar el channel de communicacion que abriste con el servidor. Reutilizas tu datainputstream para que sea el mismo durante toda la vida de la communicacion al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

The input stream should be in a loop that continuously listens to incoming message.